# Calculating time sitting in stage from time elapsed at stage

Tags: r

I have a dataset that shows time *elapsed at* each stage (ST, A, B, C, D, End)

Data:

```
    zz <- "ID  ST   A   B   C   D   End
GX001   0   0   438 0   0   520
GX002   0   182 0   0   198 331
GX003   0   0   0   92  118 118
GX004   0   0   0   0   0   218
GX005   0   24  145 0   151 159
GX006   0   0   0   0   104 111
GX007   0   0   50  0   0   56
GX008   0   0   0   2   23  30
GX009   0   0   483 0   0   507
GX010   0   67  0   0   0   137"

df <- read.table(text=zz,header=T)
```

Structure:

```
ID     ST   A   B   C   D   End
GX001   0   0   438 0   0   520
GX002   0   182 0   0   198 331
GX003   0   0   0   92  118 118
GX004   0   0   0   0   0   218
GX005   0   24  145 0   151 159
GX006   0   0   0   0   104 111
GX007   0   0   50  0   0   56
GX008   0   0   0   2   23  30
GX009   0   0   483 0   0   507
GX010   0   67  0   0   0   137
```

I want to calculate the time an observation sits *in* each stage.

For instance: `GX007` went from `ST` at 0 to stage `B` after an elapsed 50 units of time. `GX007` then went from `B` to `End` after an elapsed 56 units of time. Therefore, `GX007` spent 50 units of time in `ST` and 6 units of time in `B`.

Output:

```
ID      ST  A   B   C   D   End
GX001   438 0   82  0   0   0
GX002   182 16  0   0   133 0
GX003   92  0   0   26  0   0
GX004   218 0   0   0   0   0
GX005   24  121 6   0   8   0
GX006   104 0   0   0   7   0
GX007   50  0   6   0   0   0
GX008   2   0   0   21  7   0
GX009   483 0   24  0   0   0
GX010   67  70  0   0   0   0
```

Note: Each observation starts at *ST* and ends at *End*. Many observations skip stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom function to do this. I have assumed that all your entries are greater than or equal to 0...

```
data.frame(df[1],
    t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(r) {
        if (any(r > 0)) r[c(1, which(r>0))] <- c(r[r>0][1], diff(r[r>0]), 0)
        r
    }))
)

#      ID  ST   A  B  C   D End
#1  GX001 438   0 82  0   0   0
#2  GX002 182  16  0  0 133   0
#3  GX003  92   0  0 26   0   0
#4  GX004 218   0  0  0   0   0
#5  GX005  24 121  6  0   8   0
#6  GX006 104   0  0  0   7   0
#7  GX007  50   0  6  0   0   0
#8  GX008   2   0  0 21   7   0
#9  GX009 483   0 24  0   0   0
#10 GX010  67  70  0  0   0   0
```

Comment: `"rror: unexpected input in "data.frame(df[1],`

Comment: Could you explain what's going on in this line: `if (any(r > 0)) r[c(1, which(r>0))] <- c(r[r>0][1], diff(r[r>0]), 0)`?

Comment: It's a compact way of writing this: You first check which values are nonzero. The first entry of the result is the first nonzero value of the vector. The subsequent entries are either zero (if they were zero in the original vector), or the difference between consecutive entries in the original vector.